# Select next non empty cell in A column - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to have a button to select next non empty/blank cell in column A, relative to current row. The code below works, but only if active cell is in column A.
Need it to work on column A, even when active cell is in another column.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() 'Next step button - selects next step in A column
Dim n As Long
n = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
If ActiveCell.Row = n Then MsgBox "Last one, no more instructions.": Exit Sub

If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If ActiveCell.Column = 1` maybe?

Comment: Why do you want to select it?

Comment: I don't want it to be "if", rather no matter which column the active cell is in, to act on column A from active row. @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: @findwindow - to take user to the next cell in column A that has next line of instructions.

Comment: So do `n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` / `cells(n+1,1).select`?

Comment: @findwindow - I'd like to keep all other functionality in my code above.  And I'm not quite following what to replace, especially with that slash/  Can you post the entire code?

Comment: Please study your code.

Comment: @findwindow - and many cells in A are blank. There are random distances between non blanks.

Comment: @findwindow - I think I get which part your code before the slash replaces, but where does the line after slash supposed to go, which line to replace in my code?

Comment: `next non empty/blank cell in column A, relative to current row` it's unclear what you want. You want first blank cell in column A one encounters from the row in the active column? Edit: if one is at C5, you want first blank cell in A starting from row 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your activecell is in the wrong column. You need to address that:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() 'Next step button - selects next step in A column
Dim n As Long, fixed_range As Range
Set fixed_range = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
n = Cells(Rows.Count, fixed_range.Column).End(xlUp).Row
If fixed_range.Row = n Then MsgBox "Last one, no more instructions.": Exit Sub

If fixed_range.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
    fixed_range.End(xlDown).Select
Else
    fixed_range.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
End Sub
```

This uses a "fixed_range" to make sure we're working on column 1.

Comment: Thanks VCD_WL, how would this code be different for when MsgBox is dismissed -- either closed or OK is clicked, for this line to execute:  Range("A3").Select  @VCD_WL

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Is this what you want? `If fixed_range.Row = n Then MsgBox "Last one, no more instructions.": Range("A3").Select: Exit Sub
`

Comment: Thanks VCD_WL, that seems to do it.  I was almost there, with the exception of ":" after .Select @VCD_WL